# Creating BizTalk map with multiple input schema

Tags: mapping, biztalk

Is there anyway to create a BizTalk map with multiple input schema "from scratch" ?

i.e. not creating an orchestration and a transform shape and selecting multiple messages in the Source

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to create a multi-schema input map in Visual Studio for either BizTalk 2006, 2009 or 2013 (thanks for the clarification @Krishan) without going via the Orchestration/Transform shape route. The only other option is to manually write a map by hand in a text editor, or from a template.

Bear in mind that with the Orchestration/Transform solution, you can throw the Orchestration away once you've used it to create the map.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick 

Bit of a bummer   :-(

Yeap went the route of a scratch orchestration, but it's bit of a hassle ... any idea if this has changed in BTS 2009 ?

Comment: I've just checked and BizTalk 2009 does not add any new functionality for creating multiple input maps. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @NickHeppleston Any Update on this with regard to BizTalk 2013

Comment: @Krishan, I haven't checked on 2013 I'm afraid.

Comment: @NickHeppleston yeah in 2013 also same process folllowed

Comment: Still not possible in Visual Studio 2015 (BizTalk 2016).

Answer (score 10):

For clarity I will outline the procedure for the creation of a multiple input schema map using Visual Studio:

- Create an empty orchestration.
- Create all the message types you need (all the input messages and the output message)
- Drag a construct message shape and a transform shape onto there.
- Configure the transform shape and add all your input messages to the Transform Source list

[image: Multi source transform]

- Set the output message as usual and click OK
- A map file should appear in your project. Open it
- You will see on the left-hand side all you input messages are now available in the mapper (under Root/InputMessagePart_1, _2, etc)

[image: Multi input mapper]

You can then rename/move the map as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone still needs this, here's a template you can use.

http://fabiomarini.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/multipart-map-template/