# WCF-SQL calling stored procedure with in and out parameters

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an orchestration which receives an xml via direct binding.

In the orchestration I have to perform these tasks:

- Call 1 stored procedure to create a batch id (name IN, batchID OUT, errorCode OUT)
- Perform multiple inserts in a table matching the records in the xml (0..n unbounded), each record is one table row insert. I use a map to match the XML elements to the columns in the table.
- Call 1 stored procedure to end the batch (batchID IN, recordCount IN, errorCode OUT)

The DB calls must be done with the WCF-SQL adapter in Biztalk 2010.

My questions:

- How do I pass the batch ID of the 1st SP to the mapper (each record
  starts with a batchID column) ?
- The inserts within 1 XML must be
  regarded as one transaction. When one the inserts fails, the records
  must be rolled back. How is this achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you make you map a multi-input-schema map and use the response message from your Create Batch stored proc call as one of the input schemas. To do this see my answer to this question here [Creating BizTalk map with multiple input schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929518/creating-biztalk-map-with-multiple-input-schema/7902710#7902710)

As for your second question, if you are doing this with a table operation using the WCF-SQL adapter you can set the `useAmbientTransaction` property to true in the sqlBinding configuration which will wrap multiple calls in one transaction.

Comment: The multi root mapping is the solution here thx Hugh. UseAmbientTransaction is set to true by default, so that's covered.