# data base look up functoid

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2

I have one table which has 2 IDs.

Now I have to  check  id1 value of table1 and if it  is equal to  id of the destination schema

then i have to take the id2  from the table1 and assign it into second element in the destination schema..

How to do this using database lookup table functoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Microsoft made a big mistake to include the database functoid. The reasons for this are:

1. The SQL code generated under the hood is not performant (run a sql trace and you will see). In fact more than one connection is sometimes created.
2. The request/response to SQL server will not be handled via the send port/adapter framework. So no enterprise-level servicing is available for the call (failure handling, retries, load balancing, etc).
3. From a design perspective, it obfuscates the db calling functionality inside of a xslt which is nasty.

However, you can achieve the same ends by making the call to the database outside of the map, and then passing the response message from the DB call into the map alongside your source message you want to transform. You can add as many input messages as needed in this way.

If you want details on how to create a multi input map: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7902710/569662