# Mapping from single message to multiple message types in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, messaging

I using BizTalk to translate one message to potentially two different message types based on a value of a field in the input message.

I am looking for some guidance on how this can be achieved without using an orchestration (ideally I want a pure routing solution).

Is this possible with a custom XSLT inside a map?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually found out a way to do this by using BizTalk mapper to generate the multi-output schema template for me and then customising the generated XSLT.

Similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7902710/569662) but with multiple output schemas instead of input schemas.