# Map Output of orchestration to an element of another schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-orchestrations

I have 3 schemas which gives response as **One,Two and Three** respectively.

I have another schema which contains One,Two and Three as elements.

Is there any possible way to map these as the follows?

Say ResultSchema is the one which contains all the other output schemas as elements.

```
One ----> ResultSchema->One
Two ----> ResultSchema->Two
Three ----> ResultSchema->Three.
```

This is just like objects as properties of another object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating BizTalk map with multiple input schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929518/creating-biztalk-map-with-multiple-input-schema)

Comment: (Yes, you can, see the linked question for how)